# What is a speculative peak?

Tags: united-states, stock-markets, stock-analysis

What is everyone talking about when they say that the U.S market may be at a speculative peak? I am trying to get into investing, so I won't understand all of the jargon yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the market is high because of speculation.  Another description is a market bubble.  [Read this](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bubble.asp#:%7E:text=A%20bubble%20is%20an%20economic%20cycle%20that%20is,to%20as%20a%20%22crash%22%20or%20a%20%22bubble%20burst.%22).

Comment: "It means that the market is high because of speculation"     :)

Comment: I can't wait to add a bounty here  :)